# glPolygonMode not rendering in correct mode

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, tesselation

I recently started learning tessellation and today I was trying to draw a triangle after tessellation so that I can see all the tessellated smaller triangles using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`. But for some reason the output is just a coloured background without any triangle in it.
For the tessellation, I make a `control shader` and `evaluation shader` and then link them to the `program`.(Code below)

```
// Source code for Tesselation Control Shader
static const GLchar * tesselation_control_shader[] = 
{
    "#version 450 core                                  \n"
    "                                                   \n"
    "layout(vertices = 3) out;                          \n"
    "                                                   \n"
    "void main(void)                                    \n"
    "{                                                  \n"
    "   //Only if I am invocation 0                     \n"
    "   if (gl_InvocationID == 0)                       \n"
    "   {                                               \n"
    "       gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;                 \n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;                 \n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;                 \n"
    "       gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;                 \n"
    "   }                                               \n"
    "                                                   \n"
    "   // Everybody copies their input to their input  \n"
    "   gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position =           \n"
    "       gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;         \n"
    "}                                                  \n"
};

// Source code for tesselation evaluation shader
static const GLchar * tesselation_evaluation_shader[] =
{
    "#version 450 core                                          \n"
    "                                                           \n"
    "layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;                   \n"
    "                                                           \n"
    "void main(void)                                            \n"
    "{                                                          \n"
    "   gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position +  \n"
    "       gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position +             \n"
    "       gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position);             \n"
    "}                                                          \n"
};
```

I then call the `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` in my `render` function right before draw the triangle using `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE, 0, 3)`.
I initially thought that the `glPolygonMode` was defaulting to `GL_FILL` but I don't think that's the issue since I am just following a book (OpenGL Superbible 7th Edition).
How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
I have added the code of my entire program below:

```
GLuint compile_shaders(void)
{
    GLuint vertex_shader;
    GLuint fragment_shader;
    GLuint control_shader;
    GLuint evaluation_shader;
    GLuint program;

    // Source code for Vertex Shader
    static const GLchar * vertex_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 450 core                                                      \n"
        "                                                                       \n"
        "// offset and color are input vertex attribute                         \n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset;                                  \n"
        "layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;                                   \n"
        "                                                                       \n"
        "//Declare VS_OUT as an output interface block                          \n"
        "out VS_OUT                                                             \n"
        "{                                                                      \n"
        "   vec4 color; //Send color to next stage                              \n"
        "}vs_out;                                                               \n"
        "                                                                       \n"
        "void main(void)                                                        \n"
        "{                                                                      \n"
        "   //Decalre a hardcoded array of positions                            \n"
        "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),       \n"
        "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),      \n"
        "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));       \n"
        "                                                                       \n"
        "   //Index into our array using gl_VertexID                            \n"
        "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;                       \n"
        "                                                                       \n"
        "//color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                                    \n"
        "//Output fixed value for vs_color                                      \n"
        "vs_out.color = color;                                                  \n"
        "}                                                                      \n"
    };

    // Source code for Fragment Shader
    static const GLchar * fragment_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 450 core                                                              \n"
        "                                                                               \n"
        "//Declare VS_OUT as an input interface block                                   \n"
        "in VS_OUT                                                                      \n"
        "{                                                                              \n"
        "   vec4 color; //Send color to next stage                                      \n"
        "}fs_in;                                                                        \n"
        "                                                                               \n"
        "//Ouput to the framebuffer                                                     \n"
        "out vec4 color;                                                                \n"
        "                                                                               \n"
        "void main(void)                                                                \n"
        "{                                                                              \n"
        "// Simply assign the color we were given by the vertex shader to our output    \n"
        "   color = fs_in.color;                                                        \n"
        "}                                                                              \n"
    };

    // Source code for Tesselation Control Shader
    static const GLchar * tesselation_control_shader[] = 
    {
        "#version 450 core                                  \n"
        "                                                   \n"
        "layout(vertices = 3) out;                          \n"
        "                                                   \n"
        "void main(void)                                    \n"
        "{                                                  \n"
        "   //Only if I am invocation 0                     \n"
        "   if (gl_InvocationID == 0)                       \n"
        "   {                                               \n"
        "       gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;                 \n"
        "       gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;                 \n"
        "       gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;                 \n"
        "       gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;                 \n"
        "   }                                               \n"
        "                                                   \n"
        "   // Everybody copies their input to their input  \n"
        "   gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position =           \n"
        "       gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;         \n"
        "}                                                  \n"
    };

    // Source code for tesselation evaluation shader
    static const GLchar * tesselation_evaluation_shader[] =
    {
        "#version 450 core                                          \n"
        "                                                           \n"
        "layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;                   \n"
        "                                                           \n"
        "void main(void)                                            \n"
        "{                                                          \n"
        "   gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position +  \n"
        "       gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position +             \n"
        "       gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position);             \n"
        "}                                                          \n"
    };

    // Create and compiler Vertex Shader
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    // Create and compiler Fragment Shader
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);


    // Create and compile tesselation control shader
    control_shader = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(control_shader, 1, tesselation_control_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(control_shader);

    // Create and compile tesselation evaluation shader
    evaluation_shader = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(evaluation_shader, 1, tesselation_control_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(evaluation_shader);

    // Create program, attach shaders to it, and link it
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, control_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, evaluation_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    // Delete shaders as program has them now
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    glDeleteShader(control_shader);
    glDeleteShader(evaluation_shader);

    return program;
};

class TesselationCSOne : public sb7::application
{
public:

    void startup()
    {
        rendering_program = compile_shaders();
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
    }

    void shutdown()
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glDeleteProgram(rendering_program);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    }

    // Our rendering function
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        // Sets colour
        static const GLfloat color[] = { (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f, (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

        //Tell OpenGL to draw only the outlines of the resulting triangle
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        // Use program object we created for rendering
        glUseProgram(rendering_program);

        GLfloat attrib[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };/*{ (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f, (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f };*/

        // Update value of input attribute 0
        glVertexAttrib4fv(0, attrib);

        // Draw pathes for tesselation shaders
        glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3);
        // Draw one triangle
        glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 3);
    }

private:

    GLuint rendering_program;
    GLuint vertex_array_object;
};

// Only instance of DECLARE_MAIN to state entry point
DECLARE_MAIN(TesselationCSOne);
```

Comment: If you use a tessellation shader then you have to draw [Patches](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Patches) (`GL_PATCHES`).

Comment: Unrelated to your question but it may be worth looking into [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) rather than enclosing each line of your GLSL source in quotation marks.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I thought the Patches were done automatically (implicitly) if you use Tessellation shaders? The number of control points per patch that I need is 3. Isn't that the default value? And if it is the default value, then I don't have to call it right?

Comment: @Fibbles I shall look into that, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Varun.R You have to set the size of the patches by [`glPatchParameteri( GL_PATCH_VERTICES, ...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPatchParameter.xhtml) and the primitive type has to be `GL_PATCHES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after checking a lot of sources and the Superbible's code repository I realized I have a lot of unnecessary code (For example, the `interface blocks` in the shaders) and even quite a few mistakes (For example I had two `program` varibles).
But, after fixing all that the code that produces the required output (A tessellated triangle) is:

```
/**
        Program to draw a triangle with tesselation.
**/
#include <sb7.h>

class TesselatedTriangle : public sb7::application
{
    void init()
    {
        static const char title[] = "Tessellated Triangle";

        sb7::application::init();

        memcpy(info.title, title, sizeof(title));
    }

    virtual void startup()
    {
        static const char * vertex_shader_source[] =
        {
            "#version 450 core                                                 \n"
            "                                                                  \n"
            "void main(void)                                                   \n"
            "{                                                                 \n"
            "    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
            "                                   vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
            "                                   vec4( 0.25,  0.25, 0.5, 1.0)); \n"
            "                                                                  \n"
            "    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                          \n"
            "}                                                                 \n"
        };

        static const char * tesselation_control_shader_source[] =
        {
            "#version 450 core                                                                 \n"
            "                                                                                  \n"
            "layout (vertices = 3) out;                                                        \n"
            "                                                                                  \n"
            "void main(void)                                                                   \n"
            "{                                                                                 \n"
            "    if (gl_InvocationID == 0)                                                     \n"
            "    {                                                                             \n"
            "        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;                                               \n"
            "        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;                                               \n"
            "        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;                                               \n"
            "        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;                                               \n"
            "    }                                                                             \n"
            "    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;     \n"
            "}                                                                                 \n"
        };

        static const char * tesselation_evaluation_shader_source[] =
        {
            "#version 450 core                                                                 \n"
            "                                                                                  \n"
            "layout (triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;                                         \n"
            "                                                                                  \n"
            "void main(void)                                                                   \n"
            "{                                                                                 \n"
            "    gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position) +                       \n"
            "                  (gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position) +                       \n"
            "                  (gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position);                        \n"
            "}                                                                                 \n"
        };

        static const char * fragment_shader_source[] =
        {
            "#version 450 core                                                 \n"
            "                                                                  \n"
            "out vec4 color;                                                   \n"
            "                                                                  \n"
            "void main(void)                                                   \n"
            "{                                                                 \n"
            "    color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);                             \n"
            "}                                                                 \n"
        };

        rendering_program = glCreateProgram();

        // Compile shaders
        GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vs, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vs);

        GLuint tcs = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(tcs, 1, tesselation_control_shader_source, NULL);
        glCompileShader(tcs);

        GLuint tes = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(tes, 1, tesselation_evaluation_shader_source, NULL);
        glCompileShader(tes);

        GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fs, 1, fragment_shader_source, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fs);

        // Attach shaders to the program
        glAttachShader(rendering_program, vs);
        glAttachShader(rendering_program, tcs);
        glAttachShader(rendering_program, tes);
        glAttachShader(rendering_program, fs);

        // Link the program
        glLinkProgram(rendering_program);

        // Generate vertex arrays
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

        // Declare the drawing mode for the polygons
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    }

    virtual void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);

        glUseProgram(rendering_program);

        glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 3);
    }

    virtual void shutdown()
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);

        glDeleteProgram(rendering_program);
    }


private:

    GLuint          rendering_program;
    GLuint          vertex_array_object;

};

// One and only instance of DECLARE_MAIN
DECLARE_MAIN(TesselatedTriangle)
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a tessellation shader then you have to draw Patches. You have to set the size of the patches by [`glPatchParameteri( GL_PATCH_VERTICES, ...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPatchParameter.xhtml) and the primitive type has to be `GL_PATCHES`.

If the the number of vertices in a patch is 3, then you have to do it like this:

```
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3); 
glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 3)
```

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 10.1.15 Separate Patches; page 342](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> Separate patches are specified with mode `PATCHES`. A patch is an ordered collection of vertices used for primitive tessellation (section 11.2). The vertices comprising a patch have no implied geometric ordering. The vertices of a patch are used by tessellation shaders and the fixed-function tessellator to generate new point, line, or triangle primitives.
>
> ```
> void PatchParameteri( enum pname, int value );
> ```
>
> with pname set to `PATCH_VERTICES`

---

Your shader program doesn't even link, because the fragment shader tries to read from an input interface block,
which is not declared as an output from the previous shader stage.
You have to pass the vertex attributes, through the tessellation control and evaluation shader to the fragment shader:

Tessellation control shader:

```
#version 450 core                                 

layout(vertices = 3) out;

in VS_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
   vec4 color;                                   
} tesc_in[];

out TESC_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
   vec4 color;                                   
} tesc_out[];                          

void main(void)                                   
{                                                 
   if (gl_InvocationID == 0)                      
   {                                              
       gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0;                
       gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0;                
       gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0;                
       gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0;                
   }                                              

   tesc_out[gl_InvocationID].color     = tesc_in[gl_InvocationID].color;                    
   gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;        
}
```

Tessellation evaluation shader:

```
#version 450 core                                         

layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in; 

in TESC_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
   vec4 color;                                   
} tese_in[];

out TESE_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
   vec4 color;                                   
} tese_out;                  

void main(void)                                           
{                               
   tese_out.color = ( gl_TessCoord.x * tese_in[0].color + 
                      gl_TessCoord.y * tese_in[1].color +            
                      gl_TessCoord.z * tese_in[2].color ) / 3.0;

   gl_Position = ( gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position + 
                   gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position +            
                   gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position ) / 3.0;            
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core                                                            

in TESE_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
   vec4 color;                                  
} fs_in;                                                                      

out vec4 color;                                                              

void main(void)                                                              
{                                                                            
   color = fs_in.color;                                                      
}
```

---

Further, I recommend to check if a shader object was successfully compiled:

```
GLuint shaderObj = .... ;
glCompileShader( shaderObj );

GLint status = GL_TRUE;
glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( shaderObj, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

and a shader program object was successfully linked:

```
GLuint progObj = ....;
glLinkProgram( progObj );

GLint status = GL_TRUE;
glGetProgramiv( progObj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetProgramiv( progObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetProgramInfoLog( progObj, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout  << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

---

By the way, read about [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), which simplify the declaration of the shader source code strings:

e.g.

```
std::string fragment_shader_source = R"(
#version 450 core                                                            

in TESE_OUT                                                                    
{                                                                            
    vec4 color;                                  
} fs_in;                                                                      

out vec4 color;                                                              

void main(void)                                                              
{                                                                            
    color = fs_in.color;                                                      
}                                                                          
)";
```

---

Further note, the the `offset` probably moves the the triangle out of the viewport. Either change the value of the `offset` in the attribute initialization:

```
GLfloat attrib[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

or get rid of the `offest` in the vertex shader for debug reasons

```
gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
```

You have to ensure that the color attribute is set too:

```
GLfloat attrib1[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
glVertexAttrib4fv(1, attrib1);
```

The result may look like this:

[image: preview]

Comment: Where do I call the `glPatchParametri and glDrawArrays`? I am calling it before I draw the triangle in `render()` but the output is the same and the tessellation is still not there

Comment: @Varun.R In your question you only posted the tessellation shaders. So it is unpossible to find the issue. The code in your question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited the question and added the code of the whole program. Does that help?

Comment: I fixed what was wrong and linked the shader program as you did in the code snippets you put but the output is still a yellow screen and no triangle

Comment: @Varun.R I extended the answer.

Comment: how did you get the background to be black?
I removed the `offset` but its still just a yellow screen so I think the triangle is not visible because even it's color is yellow

Comment: @Varun.R [`glClearColor(0,0,0,0);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) [`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) at the begin of the rendering.

Comment: now it is a plain black screen with nothing else in it so the problem wasn't with the color of the triangle.

Comment: @Varun.R Have you ever seen a triangle on the screen before, without the tessellation shader?

Comment: Yeah, before the tessellation I drew just a triangle that moved ina circular fashion around the screen.
Anyway, I fixed the program. Thanks for your help